# How to subtract minutes from datetime field in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

Trying to figure how to subtract minutes from a datetime field.

```
select 
   '1' as PPCONO, b.new_SalesrepId as PPREP1, 
   MAX(a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias) as PPDATE, 
   count(b.new_SalesrepId) as PPCOUNT 
from 
   ActivityPointerBase as a
join 
   SystemUserExtensionBase as b on b.SystemUserId = a.OwnerId
join 
   UserSettingsBase as c on c.SystemUserId = b.SystemUserId
where 
   b.new_SalesrepId <> '99999999' 
   and a.ActivityTypeCode = '4201' 
   and b.new_SalesrepId is not NULL 
   and a.StateCode = '1' 
   and CONVERT(varchar(8), a.ActualEnd, 112) = '20140627'
group by 
   b.new_SalesrepId, CONVERT(varchar(8), a.ActualEnd, 112)
order by 
   b.new_SalesrepId ASC;
```

From the code above, the part `MAX(a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias)` where a.ActualEnd is the datetime field being pulled in and c.TimeZoneBias is value in minutes I am trying to subtract. Every time I run it, it subtracts days and not minutes. In this case c.TimeZoneBias actual value is '300' so it's subtracting 300 days and not 300 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the easiest way is to use arithmetic:

```
MAX(a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / cast(24 * 60 as float)) as PPDATE
```

This converts the `TimeZoneBias` into fractions of a day.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATEADD` to subtract a specific number of a specific interval, like so:

```
DATEADD(minute,  (-1 * c.TimeZoneBias), a.ActualEnd )
```

Comment: this also worked for static values. thanks for the info!